# JavaScript - Inserting and sorting elements

Tags: javascript, html

I will try to be as specific as i can.
There is a div element on the page that should contain user-list.
Users has the following properties: UserID, UserName, lvl, money.
Line that contains mentioned data contains randomly more HTML formatting.
Each user is added to the `div` using JavaScript using `+=` operator on `innerHTML`.
The list is being refreshed once in awhile and new users is added to the bottom.
Every user has its own additional div with `id="uid_" + id`, once user no longer online, he is removed by applying `style.display = "none"` on specific div.
What i'm trying (willing) to do is somehow sort users so the most rich user be on top of the list. This means that users should be inserted to more upper position, or moved to top as list refreshes.

***The list HTML may look like that:***

```
<div id='list'>
    <div id='uid_1524><font...>UserName</font><...>[15]<...>6587$<...></div>
</div>
```

***JavaScript that adds users roughly looks like this:***

```
d.getElementById('list').innerHTML += "<div id='uid.....</div>";
```

Update function looks for div as element existence and if needed, adds div to list's `innerHTML`, updates `innerHTML` of specific div, or removes div by setting `elem.style.display = 'none';`

How can i sort existing entries and resolve where next entry should be inserted (and insert it at specific point)

Comment: if you want to do the sorting on the client side, then order property in flexbox can help you.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this question by setting flexfox order property to number of money user has, and set flex-direction: column-reverse;, this way elements with higher order goes on top of the list.

**Example of code:**

```
<div id='UserList' style='display:-webkit-flex; display:flex; -webkit-flex-direction:column-reverse; flex-direction:column-reverse;'>

</div>
```

**Creating user:**

```
if (!d.getElementById("uid_" + id) {
    // Create a new element, UserNameText should contain entire line with Name, lvl, money, etc.
    d.getElementById("UserList").innerHTML += "<div id='uid_" + id + "' style='-webkit-order:" + UserMoney + "; order: " + UserMoney + ";'>" + UserNameText + "</div>";
}
```

**Removing user:**

```
if (d.getElementById("uid_" + id) {
    d.getElementById("uid_" + id).style.display = "none"; // Simply hide element
}
```

**Updating user:**

```
if (d.getElementById("uid_" + id) {
    d.getElementById("uid_" + id).innerHTML = UserNameText; // In case data needs to be updated
    d.getElementById("uid_" + id).style.display = "block"; // In case it was hidden
    d.getElementById("uid_" + id).style.order = UserMoney; // In case position needs to be updated
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the list is always sorted. To insert a new user, find an existing user that has the least amount of money greater than the user to insert, then use `Element.insertAdjacentHTML()` to add the new user.

For example

```
var previous = findPreviousUser();
previous.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "<div id='uid.....</div>");
```

Alternatively, you can find the first user that has a lower amount of money than the current user, and then use `insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', ...)` to insert the current user before it.

See more info here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: What about scenario when the user receives more money after he was placed to the list? As was said before, the list is being updated once in awhile, can i move existing div? (Remove and Re-Create maybe?)

Comment: Yea, I would remove that user from the list and re-add it to the correct location

Comment: To remove it just get it by id ``var element = document.getElementById("uid");
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);``

Answer (score 0):

You could use an object orientated design paatern and keep track of users and the value to order them like this:

Untested "pseudocode".

```
var user_ranking = (function(){

    function user_ranking(){
        this.user_element = document.getElementById('user-container');
        this.rank_map      = {};
        this.user_map      = {};
        this.user_map_html = {};
    }
    user_ranking.prototype.add_user = function( user_details ){
        this.rank_map[user_details.rank] = user_details.uid;
        this.user_map[user_details.uid]  = user_details.rank;
        this.add_user_to_dom( user_details );
    };
    user_ranking.prototype.remove_user = function(uid){
    };
    user_ranking.prototype.add_user_to_dom = function( user_details ){

        var new_child = this.template( user_details );
        this.user_map_html[user_details.uid] = new_child;

        var rank_uid   = this.get_rank( user_details );
        var rank_child = this.user_map_html[rank_uid];

        this.user_element.insertBefore( new_child, rank_child );
        /** or after etc. **/

    };
    user_ranking.prototype.get_rank = function( user_details ){
        /** logic to get the rank you want **/
        /** loop over rank_map keys and check for the user_id of the previous / next rank **/
        return wanted_user_id;
    }
    user_ranking.prototype.template = function( user_details ){
        /** logic to get the rank you want **/
        var element = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHtml = user_details.html;
        return li;
    }

    return new user_ranking();

})();

/** usage **/
user_ranking.add_user( user_details );
```